# Is this a collectable bicycle?

Tags: road-bike

I have purchased a new bicycle, it is a clasical one (downtube shifters etc). I want to use it for commuting. Some guys told me that it might be a collectable bike and maybe i should try and find a bike colectioner before ruining it as beater bike.

I have posted picture of it here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEdD2.jpg

Comment: It's definitely a nice bike -- was a fairly expensive one when new, and it's quite clean for its age (I suspect it's not been ridden that much).  Appears to be geared for racing, so maybe not ideal as a "beater".  Whether it's worth anything or not is hard to say, but it's probably worth a bit of investigating.

Comment: That's a pretty nice bike. If it was mine, I'd ride it - that's what bikes are for, not for hanging on a wall. If you maintain it diligently, don't crash it, and park it in a safe spot, it should serve you well for many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good Campagnolo parts on it which may be collectible, and it is a Masi frame, which held quite a bit of value for some time. It's not in bad shape, but not so good as to justify mint condition collector value.

I doubt it has any serious value even fully restored unless it was actually ridden by Fausto Coppi or Eddy Merckx (which is understandably unlikely), but if you take the time for a restoration, you may get a couple thousand or so dollars from a collector with a particular interest in Masi.

Anything beyond that would require a specialist in the subject, and provenance on the frame.